# Is there an accurate way to get all of the stored procedure column dependencies in Sybase ASE?

Tags: sap-ase

I am currently working within a Sybase ASE 15.7 server and need a dependable way to get all of the stored procedures which are dependent upon a particular column. The Sybase system procedure sp_depends is notoriously unreliable for this. I was wondering if anyone out there had a more accurate way to discover these dependencies.

Apparently, the IDs of the columns are supposed to be stored in a bitmap in the varbinary column sysdepends.columns. However, I have not yet found a bitmask which has been effective in decoding these column IDs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a tedious solution could be to parse the SP code in the system table syscomments to retrieve the tables.

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution might be to run sp_recompile on all relevant tables, then watch master..monCachedProcedures to see changes in the CompileDate.   Note that the CompileDate will only change once the stored proc has been executed after the sp_recompile (it actually gets compiled on 1st execution)

This would at least give you an idea of stored procedures that are in use, that are dependent on the specified table.

Not exactly elegant...